# Is it possible to access a controller's instance variable in a partial if the partial is being rendered by a different controller's view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering, partial-views

Hi guys thanks in advance for the help. I am building a sort of online game using rails. The user interface is all supposed to be centered around one page: users/... I am running into an issue in creating and interacting with objects outside of users. For example, within the user page users are supposed to have the ability to create a fortress. The fortress of course is its own object with its own model and controller. If I were to try to put a form to create a fort using the form_for tag in the users page, the form wouldn't be able to access the fort controller's @fort instance variable and would throw an error. In my attempt to solve the problem I have created a partial view for forts called _new.html.erb containing the fort form

Here it is:

```
<h1>Create a New Fort</h1>
    <%= form_for(@fort) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :ownership %>
      <%= f.text_field :ownership %>

<div style="display:none;">

      <%= f.label :xco %>
      <%= f.text_field :xco %>

      <%= f.label :yco %>
      <%= f.text_field :yco %>

      <%= f.label :territory %>
      <%= f.password_field :territory %>

</div>

      <%= f.submit "Create a Fort" %>
    <% end %>
```

I then render that partial in my user show.html.erb here:

```
<%= render "forts/new" %>
```

Of course moving the form to a partial does nothing at all, but what I was hoping to do was something along the lines of this:

```
<%= render partial: "new", object: @fort %>
```

I would like to pass the fort instance variable into the partial then render the partial in the users view. I recognize however that the variable passed to the partial as described above comes directly from the view the partial is rendered in, and at that realization I am at a loss for ideas.

I have considered the key might be somewhere in associations and I have been crawling the internet for info on that. My models are set up so a user has_many forts and a fort belongs_to a user. I don't know whether or not that will help.

All help is appreciated,

Thanks loads,

Alex P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for). [This](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) RailsCast explains how it is used.

In your case you would add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :forts` to your user model. I'm not sure what your user/show view looks like, but you should just be able to add a `<%= f.fields_for :forts do |f| %>` which would contain the fields currently in forts/new.

Answer (score 1):

From your outer view, assuming @fort has been instantiated in your controller, you can pass @fort directly to your partial like this:

```
<%= render 'forts/new', :fort => @fort %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass Locals with render statements wherever you call partial.

```
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :locals => {:info => first, :img_style => "original"} %>
```